# C# How do I use a variable in a Linq select statement using Query Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the name of item but I'm having to hard code the locale in the select statement. This is my code

```
private void GetOrder(Root Wix)
    {
        string locale = Wix.restaurant.locale;
        List<Item> menu = Wix.menu.items;
        List<OrderItem> orderItems = Wix.order.orderItems;
        foreach (var orderItem in orderItems)
        {
            string itemId = orderItem.itemId;
            string itemName = (from m in menu  where m.id==itemId select m.title.en_GB).FirstOrDefault();

            int count = orderItem.count;
            string comment = orderItem.comment;
            int price = orderItem.price;
        }

        string orderComment = Wix.order.comment;
        int totalPrice = Wix.order.price;
    }
```

How can I replace the hard coded "en_GB" in select m.title.en_GB to the locale value returned in the string locale = Wix.restaurant.locale ?

Comment: Please provide source code of `Item` class and classes used in it.

Comment: And you can also remove `linq` tag from question, it is not related to LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
string itemName = (from m in menu  where m.id==itemId select (string)m.title.GetType().GetProperty(locale).GetValue(m.title)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will throw an exception if the class of your `title` object has no property that has the same name as the content of the string `locale`. The following variant will make your `itemName` null if no such property exists:

```
string itemName = (from m in menu  where m.id==itemId select (string)m.title.GetType().GetProperty(locale)?.GetValue(m.title)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an error; "Object does not match target type." when I use either of the 2 statements above

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I already updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using slow reflection based approach you can introduce interface like this

```
public interface ILocalizableString
{
    string en_GB { get; }

    string ru_RU { get; }

    //and so on
}
```

Implement it by your localized strings and introduce extension method

```
public static class LocalizableStringExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this ILocalizableString str, string locale)
    {
        if(str == null)
            return null;
        if(locale == "en_GB")
            return str.en_GB;
        if(locale == "ru_RU")
            return str.ru_RU;
        return str.en_GB; //default
     }
  }
```

Then in your code

```
  string itemName = (from m in menu  where m.id==itemId select m.title.GetString(locale)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This can guarantee good performance, and simple way to extended list of supported languages.

Comment: I'd suggest using switch expression instead of `if` - `else` statements.
`
            return locale switch
            {
                "en_GB" => item.title.en_GB,
                "ru_RU" => item.title.ru_RU,
                ...
                _ => "undefined"
            };
`

Comment: I think switch expressions are too recent to use them in answers, many people can find them unfamiliar, or may be restricted in language version. If/return approach is clear and obvious, and those who want will convert it to switch or whatever they need.